# installation of daemon service with the help of Aur where will be files install and which files

Tags: linux, archlinux

How to get the location and name of files if we install daemon service in arch Linux. and what will be the command to get the list of files that are added in by the install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To obtain the list of files that are included in an installed package (from AUR or not), simply do:

```
pacman -Ql package_name
```

and if you only want one path per line (to use in a script), use:

```
pacman -Qql package_name
```